# Regex starts and/or ends with string - how to simplify?

Tags: regex

I have a string that might start and/or end with `;`. I want to match and replace these `;` strings. The following regex works, but how can I make it simpler?

```
(?:^(; ).*)(?:.*(; )$)|(?:^(; ).*)|(?:.*(; )$)
```

This uses the structure AB|A|B (A and B, or A, or B).

Example strings:

- `; foo ;bar;` (2 matches)
- `foo ;bar;` (1 match)
- `; foo ;bar` (1 match)
- `foo ;bar` (0 matches)

Comment: The outer non-capturing groups only impact readability. What is the expected output, BTW? Try [`^;\s*|;\s*$`](https://regex101.com/r/bxvKtd/1) .

Comment: Four cases, why not first handle all starts and then all ends. Then you have 2 independent cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that non-capturing groups are meant to group sequences of patterns, and if you do not quantify the group, nor use alternatives inside, the non-capturing group becomes redundant. So, you regex will look like `^(; ).*.*(; )$|^(; ).*|.*(; )$` without those groups and you easily see that there is a double `.*` in the first alternative. Reducing the pattern to `^(; ).*(; )$|^(; ).*|.*(; )$` you can see that if the first part is not matched, the second or third will find `;` followed with a space either at the start or end, so the first alternative looks redundant (unless you need to split the replacement logic for 3 cases!).

So, if you just want to replace the match with 1 replacement pattern, you may just use

```
^;\s*|;\s*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bxvKtd/2)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Regular Expression code

```
^\;|\;$
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/C9ZnWJ/2

Comment: Thanks for this. Unlike the answer above, however this does not match the spaces.